# Authentication with Twitter in an Angular App

Tags: angular, twitter, oauth

I'm building an application that will allow a user to log in to multiple Twitter accounts and view their activity in each of the accounts. Think TweetDeck-like functionality.

I'm using Auth0 to authenticate to the actual application, and don't want these Twitter accounts that they sign in to to be the authentication for the application. But what I want is for them to click an "Add Twitter account" button, which takes them to Twitter, they log in, and a token is returned. That token can then be stored to make API calls to Twitter to get the timelines and needed data.

The problem is that I can't find a library to help me achieve this, or figure out how to use the `HttpClientModule` to accomplish this. It seems like everything I find is just to do authentication to an entire application with a single Twitter account. I did see that [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#oauth-signing) seems to be able to accomplish this, but it appears that it's only available in a Node application, so that doesn't help much.

What's the best way to move forward from here and accomplish this? Is there a way to do this using Angular and the `HttpClient`? Or a library that would help?

***Edit***

I have access to a Node.js backend, and can use that as well. In fact, that's where I'll query the Twitter API. I just want to kick off the "Sign in with Twitter" flow from the Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

Do I see it right, that you are looking for a solution that allows your Angular Application to talk to Auth0?

Comment: No, not exactly. I have already authenticated with Auth0 in the app. So that part is done. What I want to do is let the user (after logging in to the app) connect one or more Twitter accounts to the app so that the app can gather that Twitter information in one spot. So they would click a button, get sent to Twitter to log in, and then it'd return to the application with a token that can be used to query the Twitter API for that user's information. Does that make sense?